# "Missing semicolon" error on Async function declaration

Tags: javascript, async-await

In a Vue app, I want to group js functions in a js file. In getData.js , I have the following:

```
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import { db } from "./firebase/index";
import store from "../store/index"

  
  async getProjects () { 
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "projects"));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      let project = doc.data()
      project.id = doc.id
      store.state.currentProjectList.push(project)
    });
  }



  export { getProjects }
```

I get the "Missing semicolon." error on the line where I declare the function: async getProjects().

(I know this isn't the way to add data to the store but this is only for testing purpose)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: add function in front of getProjects: `async function getProjects () `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async getProjects () {` is [method declaration syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions); it is only allowed *inside an object or class definition*.

To create a local function you need to use a function declaration or an arrow function.

```
async function getProjects () {
```

or

```
const getProjects = async () => {
```

(You could also use a function expression, but that gets even further from the syntax you had).

---

You also have a missing semi-colon at the of the previous line – `import store from "../store/index"` which isn't a JS error (but might be a linting error if you are using a linter and didn't mention that).

Comment: In general, the use of a linter is recommended. For inlining but also missing semicolons etc.